# Union types in TypeScript - can I achieve this?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to achieve the following:

```
class MyClass {    
  boolProp: boolean;  
}

let a: string | MyClass;
a.boolProp = false; // error
```

The last line throws an error since that's how typescript works.

Can I achieve the above without an error, but without **typeguards**?
I just want to be able to tell the compiler that a certain variable is either of type a or b, so it should consider it a 'real' union of **both** type properties and methods, not just the common ones.

I'm familiar with such behaviors from other languages and to my taste this seems like a feature request for typescript.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the complement to type unions, [type intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

```
class MyClass {    
  boolProp: boolean;  
}

let a: string & MyClass;
a.boolProp = false; // no error
```

Type unions announce a variable is one type or another, so the only properties you can reliably access are those common to both. Type intersection announce a variable satisfies both type contracts, so you can access properties that belong to either of its component types -- which is what you want.

Comment: that's what i've been looking for! thanks! Strangely, the naming is the opposite of the natural meaning of it (at least in my mind): "intersection" and "union" could be replaced. Also, the type writing is opposite as well. If I type myVar: a | b; I would expect myVar to be of type a OR b, meaning accessing any of these types properties would have gone unharmed. But this is just repeating myself... . Thanks again!

Comment: @BoazRymland I'd like to poke at something. You said " I would expect myVar to be of type a OR b". That is indeed what that means. But then you said "meaning accessing any of these types properties would have gone unharmed" if type safety is a concern, then we logically can't guarantee that accessing a member of `a` is safe, because `myVar` may actually be of type `b`. We can only guarantee that properties that `a` and `b` **both** have are safe to access.

Comment: @BoazRymland type can be viewed as a set of all possible values that conform to that type. So intersection type corresponds to the intersection of these sets. If both types are object types with named properties, and if the value belong to both of these types (to the intersection type), then the value must have all properties from both types, so intersection of object types has union of their properties. So it's naturally meaning "intersection" if you look from one side, and "union" if you look from the other side - that's what they call duality.

Comment: @Paarth yeah, i understand what you mean, and I accept that. Its a way of thought I'll have to think more and perhaps even adopt. IMHO, when I accept in my code a variable to be of type A or B, I always remember while coding that it can be of type... A or B... :-) . Meaning, **I** take that into account and have to regard this. Your/TS approach is arguably safer or tighter, but it doesn't play with my way of thinking.

Comment: @artem Thanks for the extra words

Answer (score 3):

Union types, by definition, contain only the [common properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types):

> If we have a value that has a union type, we can only access members
>   that are common to all types in the union

At runtime you'll need to check whether a specific value is a `string` or `MyClass` to understand if `boolProp` is a property of said value, and that's where the type guards come into action.

If in your code you're creating a `boolProp` property to `string` instances, then you better do something like:

```
type MyString = string & { boolProp: boolean };
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
let a: MyString | MyClass;
a.boolProp = false; // works
```

This way you'll differentiate between string instances which have `boolProp` and instances that don't.